# How to manage multiple kubernetes clusters via Terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to create a secret in several k8s clusters in the Google Kubernetes Engine using the Terraform.

I know that I can use "host", "token" and some else parameters in "kubernetes" provider,  but I can describe these parameters only once, and I don’t know how to connect to another cluster during the file of terraform.

My question is how to create a secret (or do other operations) in multiple k8s cluster via Terraform. Maybe you know some tools on github or other tips for doing via single terraform file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use alias for provider in terraform like described in [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#alias-multiple-provider-instances)

So you can define multiple providers for multiple k8s clusters and then refer them by alias.

e.g.

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_context_auth_info = "ops1"
  config_context_cluster   = "mycluster1"
  alias = "cluster1"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  config_context_auth_info = "ops2"
  config_context_cluster   = "mycluster2"
  alias = "cluster2"
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "example" {
  ...
  provider = kubernetes.cluster1
}
```

Comment: Is there a way that I could do the provider declaration in a loop? Let's say I have 50 clusters. It would be difficult to declare all of them manually using your current approach.

Comment: It isn't possible no as it's set up front. Functionality I'm after too...

Comment: You don't need to provide an alias for every provider. Than if you don't specify a provider in a resource, the default provider will be used (the one without an alias).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using terraform submodules, the setup is a bit more involved. See [this terraform github issue comment](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/28490#issuecomment-976939379).