# Loop over multiple kube context to install helm chart with terraform

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

I am still discovering TF, sorry if the question makes no sense :)

I am installing helm chart with a Terraform script. I am using this [helm provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs).
This works well on my test cluster.

I want now to iterate over all my clusters. I wanted to perform a for_each loop, but I can not find how to actually switch/provide what cluster/context to use.
How can I specify to use a specific context?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to use a for_each loop inside of a provider block, but there is a way to create multiple providers and assign aliases to each [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861264/how-to-manage-multiple-kubernetes-clusters-via-terraform).

Comment: Thanks that looks good !