# terraform for_each for provider and data block

Tags: terraform

I have a locals value as:

```
[
  {
    "name": "dev",
    "region": "us-east4",
    "min_gke_nodes" : "2",
    "max_gke_nodes" : "4",
    "cluster_subnet" : "subnet-1"
  },
  {
    "name": "prod",
    "region": "us-central1",
    "min_gke_nodes" : "20",
    "max_gke_nodes" : "40",
    "cluster_subnet" : "subnet-2"
  }
]
```

For each of the locals json block, I want to connect to each cluster and do some changes.

I am using :

```
data "google_client_config" "provider" {}
data "google_container_cluster" "gke" {
  for_each = { for idx, val in local.clusters : idx => val } #THIS CANNOT BE USED.

  name     = each.value.name
  location = each.value.region
  project  = var.project_id
}
provider "kubernetes" {
  for_each = { for idx, val in local.clusters : idx => val } #THIS CANNOT BE USED.
  host  = "https://${data.google_container_cluster.gke.endpoint}"
  token = data.google_client_config.provider.access_token
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(
    data.google_container_cluster.gke.master_auth[0].cluster_ca_certificate,
  )
  alias = "gke"
}
```

Since `data` and `provider` blocks cannot use `for_each`, I can not connect using loop. Is there a way I can use anything else?

Comment: It looks like a common thing not supported by Terraform. I've faced this issue at least twice this year, and after tweaking everything I could, I finally gave up because it doesn't look possible. While you _can_ technically use provider aliases, these just won't work if you create your clusters dynamically like you do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861264/how-to-manage-multiple-kubernetes-clusters-via-terraform#comment118479740_57861476. You can't even define modules, because if you use a provider in the module, you won't be able to do `for_each`.

Comment: When I said "I gave up" I meant I don't use the `kubernetes` provider anymore **when managing multiple clusters**. There is a "hack" where you can use one workspace per cluster (`cluster1`, `cluster2`) and as much tfvars file (`cluster1.tfvars`, `cluster2.tfvars`), but it's hard to manage and awful if you want to be sure all your clusters have the same resources in it. I've tried this, but finally resorted to provision my clusters outside Terraform (with FluxCD). I really wish there was a solution I have missed, so I'll upvote the question and follow it. Sorry my comment didn't help you much.